# Animating child view controller view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a child view controller, and I want to add a button on the parent view controller. when the button is clicked, I want the child VC to appear from the bottom of the screen to the half of it.
I tried to animate the height constraint, but for some reason, it won't start from the bottom of the screen. so the animation looks weird. It starts above the bottom and goes up and down until it gets to the constant value I specified.
This is what I have:

```
    func setChildVC() {
    self.addChild(childVC)
    mainView.addSubview(childVC.view)

    childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    childVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    heightAnchor =             childVC.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        childVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        childVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        childVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor),
        heightAnchor,
    ])
}
```

And this Is how I animate the height (currently on viewDidLoad):

```
self.heightAnchor.constant = 350
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.childVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I tried to set the y axis of the `childVC.view` to be below the screen, but because of the constraints it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
self.childVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

with

```
self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to correctly test it don't try it inside `viewDidLoad` it's too early , also for the sake of different screen heights do

```
self.heightAnchor.constant = self.view.frame.height / 2.0
```